# Why is it showing this error: raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative") ValueError: Sample larger than population

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make two lists with random numbers with random length (they don't have to be the same).
Can you tell me why I'm getting this error:

raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

```
import random
size = random.randint(6,20)
a = list(random.sample(range(1,9),size))
size = random.randint(6,10)
b = list(random.sample(range(1,7),size))
#a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
#b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = []
for number in a:
    for num in b:
        if(number==num):
            if not number in c:
                c.append(number)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Given this code `random.sample(range(1,9), size)`, when `size` is greater than 8 you will get the error because `range(1,9)` has only 8 elements/numbers. `random.randint(6,20)` can return an int up to 20 which is way more than the size of the range

Comment: but isn't it a range for random (i mean that random numbers will be within this range). I want to make two different sizes lists, with high possibility of same random numbers

Answer (score 2):

You want e.g. `random.choices(range(1,9), k=size)` instead of `random.sample(...)`. `sample` does not repeat elements in a set, so the count requested must be less than the length of the set.